# how can we remove string from rows in a file following a particular pattern?

Tags: linux, unix

I have a plaintext file with many rows with same name:

```
./intuit
./intuit/apac-trial13
./safenetdatasecurityisraelltd3
./safenetdatasecurityisraelltd3/ldk-emea-eval
```

I want to delete `./` from all rows 
and also

```
./intuit
./safenetdatasecurityisraelltd3
```

Any unix command with help of which I can delete `./` from all rows and row without subdirectories

Comment: Do you need a shellscript for that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it might belong to http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/26071/ras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed -n 's@^\./@@; /\// p' test.txt
intuit/apac-trial13
safenetdatasecurityisraelltd3/ldk-emea-eval
```

What did we do there?  `sed -n` says "don't print unless I say so."  Then, `s@^\./@@` removes the leading `./` if present.  Finally, we match any line with a `/` (escaped appropriately), and print it with `p`.

Answer (score 1):

In UNIX, you can always combine multiple commands to get things done.

As you mentioned, first you want to remove leading `./` from each line. So, use `sed` to replace leading `./` with nothing:

```
$ sed 's:^\./::' input.txt 
intuit
intuit/apac-trial13
safenetdatasecurityisraelltd3
safenetdatasecurityisraelltd3/ldk-emea-eval
```

Then, next thing you want on top of this is listing of lines with subdirectories in it. Now, to identify if line has sub-directories, one way is to look if it has `/`.

```
$ sed 's:^\./::' input.txt | grep '/'
intuit/apac-trial13
safenetdatasecurityisraelltd3/ldk-emea-eval
```

In UNIX, you can pass the output of one command as an input to other command using `|`.